# Remove enter key delay in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm testing an HTML form, and this requires me to refresh the page to see the updated changes.

I want to refresh the page without sending any POST data, but if I press F5 or the refresh button this shows up instead:

> [image]

So instead, I have to highlight the URL bar, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That is all fine, but there is a massive delay from being able to press Enter and refresh the page.

Try it:

1. Open any page in Chrome
2. Click the URL box
3. Spam the Enter key multiple times and see that the page does not refresh

Is there a way to remove this delay?

Other browsers do not have this delay, and I don't recall previous versions of Chrome doing this either.

Comment: Temp solution: Bookmark the URL I'm testing, and just click on the bookmark.

Comment: Can confirm the delay. It's frustrating. No one else I know seems to have the problem. I'm on macOS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has continued to annoy me. With the help of a colleague, I discovered that the history sync was causing the problem for me. Disabling this, removes the delay that seems to have snuck in during the past few weeks.

[Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w3mC.png)

Comment: Oh my gosh what! It completely removed the delay. Some quirky settings, but it definitely worked.

Comment: That made my day so much better, thanks. Also worked here.

Comment: Thanks ! That was driving me crazy I can't understand how they manage to mess this up.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Web Inspector.

This confirmation dialog is not displayed if the inspector is open.

Comment: A great solution too! And it makes sense because I would probably have the developer's console open when debugging forms anyways.

Answer (score -1):

In my case turn off sync **Open tabs** helped me

Comment: Please describe how to do that.    Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.